# I am getting a Unicode Error when attempting to run Pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I'm trying to run pytest but it seems to be throwing some form of a unicode error when I try to run it. I can't even get the help to display for the package without getting this error. For example, the response to my command

```
pytest -h
```

throws me the error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 1064: character maps to <undefined>
```

I've tried both reinstalling and upgrading. Anyone have any ideas why this is happening? I get the same error no matter what pytest command I run

Edit: I've tried this on a fresh Anaconda install of python 3.8 which included pytest. I additionally ran pip install pytest --upgrade to see if that would help. The Environment is the base conda environment with no additionally packages installed beyond what comes bundled into Anaconda

Comment: Can you show how you installed pytest ? and which environment are you using ?

Comment: Check `locale` to see what kind of character encoding your terminal is using

Comment: In case this happens to you on PyCharm, changing the default encoding solves this problem: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-55463